# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UITableView reloadData call

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates, exc-bad-access

I've come to the point of pulling my hair out over this one.  I keep getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I call the reloadData for the UITableView.  I'll lay the groundwork for you here.

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class iPROSAppDelegate;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
 iPROSAppDelegate *parent;

 ...

 NSMutableArray *contentSeqList;
 UITableView *contentSeqTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iPROSAppDelegate *parent;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *contentSeqList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *contentSeqTable;
...
- (IBAction)changeMainView:(id)sender;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)changeMainView:(id)sender{
    //do logs to make sure we get here and grab an NSDictionary object from another class
 NSLog(@"got to a change of main view");
 NSDictionary *myContentSequences = [[parent csList] grabCSListandReturnJSON:[sender tag]];
 NSLog(@"got cs list for tag %@: %@", [sender currentTitle], myContentSequences);

    //set up table view
 contentSeqTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 240, 300) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
 contentSeqTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
 [contentSeqTable setDelegate:self];
 [contentSeqTable setDataSource:self];
 NSLog(@"delegate: %@, data source: %@", [contentSeqTable delegate], [contentSeqTable dataSource]);
 contentSeqList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //populate nsmutablearray contentseqlist using the nsdictionary mycontentsequences
 for (id dashboard in [myContentSequences objectForKey:@"dashboards"]){
  if ([dashboard objectForKey:@"error"] == nil){
   for (id contentsequence in [dashboard objectForKey:@"contentSequences"]){
    [contentSeqList addObject:[contentsequence objectForKey:@"name"]];
    NSLog(@"added object to content sequence list: %@", [contentsequence objectForKey:@"name"]);
   }
  }
 }
 [contentSeqTable reloadData];
 ...
}
```

changeMainView is called when a button is clicked in the main view.  Here are the delegate methods also for UITableView.  Notice that the NSLogs are the first lines in these methods, but I get neither showing in the console log before the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 NSLog(@"content seq list count: %@", [contentSeqList count]);
 return [contentSeqList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
 NSLog(@"setting up the cells");
 NSUInteger index = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];

 NSString *myId = @"id";
 if (tableView.editing) myId = @"idE";

 UILabel *name;

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myId];

 if (cell == nil){
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 20)  reuseIdentifier:myId] autorelease];

  float width = 260;
  if (tableView.editing) width = 240;

  name = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 1, width, 53)] autorelease];
  [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [name setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 18]];
  [name setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
  [name setMinimumFontSize:11];
  [name setNumberOfLines:2];

  name.tag = 1;

  [cell.contentView addSubview:name];

 }
 else{
  name = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
 }

 if ([tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]){
  if (indexPath == [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]){  
   [name setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  }
  else{
   [name setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  }
 }
 else{
  [name setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
 }

 [name setText:[contentSeqList objectAtIndex:index]];

 return cell;
}
```

The delegate methods are part of the same class, MainViewController.  I've also checked that the UITableView was not nil via NSLog right before reloadData. I know I have to be missing something small here.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show call stack when `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` occurs?

BTW,

```
NSUInteger index = [indexPath row];
```

is much more readable than

```
NSUInteger index = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
```

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot to check the call stack from debugger.  Thanks for the suggestion, it was a problem with the NSLog in numberOfRowsInSection: where I was trying to do %@ when I should have used %d.  Thanks!